# Does C# support bit fields (bit packing) in structure?

Tags: c#

I think bit fields are not possible in c# structure but it is possible in c++.
For Example:

```
typedef struct
{

    UINT16 SrcPort:16;
    UINT16 DstPort:16;
    UINT32 SeqNum:32;
    UINT32 AckNum:16;
    UINT16 Reserved1:4;
    UINT16 HdrLength:4;

}IP_HDR
```

How can we create a structure like this in c# with bit fields?

My question is how we can set bit fields in C# structure.Is there any ways to do it in C#?

Comment: Might be related (not knowledgeable of the topic enough to know for sure): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311478/marshalling-stucts-with-bit-fields-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: This might also help: [Bit fields in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

No, C# does not offer any language features to define or access data storage smaller than 1 byte.  You will have to mask and shift to isolate bit subranges within the data.