# How should I implement a BitOffset something like FieldOffset?

Tags: c#

all,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit,Pack =1)]
public struct C {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte F1;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte F2;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public int F3;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte F4;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit,Pack =1)]
public struct BitTest{

[FieldOffset(0)]
[BitOffset(0)]
public Bit1 F1;
[FieldOffset(0)]
[BitOffset(1)]
public Bit2 F2;
[FieldOffset(0)]
[BitOffset(3)]
public Bit5 F3;
}
```

How should I implement something like FieldOffset.
I want to create some bit-based types. For example Bit3, when I define them in a structure, I want to be able to control their memory layout in bytes.

It's like using FieldOffset to control the memory layout of fields in a structure.
But I don't know how to do it.

For example, for the Bit5 field above, I can easily write the BitOffset type. But how should I change the location of Bit5 in the memory? Logically, it should start from the 3 bit of the 1 byte of the structure BitTest. Go to bits of length 5. But how to do all this.

Comment: No you cannot write your own attributes like `BitOffset`. I don't think the CLR even allows you to do anything below the "byte" level. Why not just use a `byte`, and make property getters for the bits you want by shifting?

Comment: Anyway, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591/5133585) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9311478/5133585) are some related posts.